# Accessing columns of a matrix based function output

Tags: matlab

I have a function which returns an nxk matrix. Suppose I wanted to take each column of the matrix into a different variable, is there a one line way I can do this?

Currently I am doing (for k=3)

```
A = MyFunc(...);
x1 = A(:, 1);
x2 = A(:, 2);
x3 = A(:, 3);
```

I notice that doing

```
[x1, x2, x3] = MyFunc(...);
```

does not work but is there anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the output of your function into a cell, then use `deal` to assign that to multiple arrays:

```
A = MyFunc(...);
Acell = mat2cell(A,size(A,1),ones(1,size(A,2)));
[x1, x2, x3] = deal(Acell{:});
```

This will cut `A` into a cell array according to its columns, but then you must have the same number of variables on the left side of `deal`.

Alternatively, you can decide how to cut the columns with `mat2cell`. For instance, you can cut an array of size `[5,6]` into arrays of size `[5,2]`, `[5,3]` and `[5,1]` with `mat2cell(A,size(A,1),[2 3 1]);`.

Comment: First, I'd like to mod up for clever! Lol, but second, I'd like to mod down because it introduces needless obfuscation!

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks! Yeah, I know, I was on a needless-use-of-deal rampage yesterday;) I've been trying to figure out an actual use case where you can do this with a variable number of arguments *without `eval`*, but I haven't succeeded yet. I have a hunch that OP needs more variables, but true, my solution doesn't start to spare keyboard time up until a dozen variables:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't join the one line programming cult, sacrificing readability and performance for the weirdo objective of using as few lines as possible!

Unless you have a huge number of variables, suck it up and do:

```
A = MyFunc(...);
x1 = A(:, 1);
x2 = A(:, 2);
x3 = A(:, 3);
```

Everyone can instantly read it. But if you're already a cult member and have just GOT to put it one line:

```
 A=MyFunc(...);x1=A(:, 1);x2=A(:, 2);x3=A(:,3);
```

Before you knock it, realize that's almost certainly faster than anyone else's one line answer!

Comment: Or, one could probably go for "change your function definition to return multiple variables". Ah-ha! Then we could use `deal`!:D